# WebClient FTP upload creates bin and hqx files

Tags: c#, ftp

I am trying to upload a `String` to an FTP server. It works but it creates a `bin` and a `hqx` file additionally. Question is: How can I omit these files when using `WebClient`.

The code is:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Setting.FtpUsername, Setting.FtpPassword);
    client.UploadString(filename, json);
}
```

Comment: This is not a feature of the `WebClient`, what FTP server is it?

Comment: I am not sure which FTP server software they are using.

Comment: Well it's their side which is probably doing this.